# Cannot deploy an AIR application to an iPod Touch

Tags: air, flash-builder, ipod-touch

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 with Flex SDK 4.5.1, and when trying to deploy an app to a 2nd gen iPod Touch with latest available iOS I get an error saying the app is not valid, and according to some Adobe sites, only 1st generation iPods aren't supported. The application works fine in an iPhone.

Should I change some setting, update to AIR SDK 3.1, or am I wrong thinking my app should work on this device despite Adobe's pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I managed to gather a week ago, Adobe dropped iPod Touch 2ng Gen support with AIR 2.6 (or even 2.5, I don't know for sure).

However, one may be able to compile a Flex Mobile project targetting an old AIR SDK version (or a more recent one if you can target Flash 10.1), and then use PFI (the old packager for iPhone before it was combined with ADT) so your application works with older iOS devices.

Sadly, my current project is forced to use ANE, so I guess I must forget about supporting old devices.

Comment: Just needed to know if i upgrade the 2nd gen iPod to iOS 4.2, will the adobe air 2.5 support it?

Comment: I don't know about 2.5, previous AIR versions should work, later ones won't work even if you have latest iOS installed.